# Give an example of a set A that is not closed but such that every point of A is a limit-point.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm feeling a bit iffy about this proof because I feel like I'm misinterpreting the problem: doesn't any open interval on the real line work?

Let $A = (0,1)$. $A$ is not closed because $0, 1$ are limit points, but $0,1 \notin A$. Now, grab an arbitrary $x \in A$ and consider the neighborhood $(x-1/n,x+1/n)$. If $x-1/n > 0$ and $x+1/n < 1$, then let $y$ be any point in the interval and we are done; for instance, $y = x + 1/2n$. If, however, $x + 1/n\geq 1$, then keep shrinking $n$ until $x + 1/n < 1$. A fast way to do this is to do $1 - x$ to find the distance from $x$ and 1, and then divide by $2$, so $(1-x)/2$. By the Axiom of Archimedes, we can find an $n$ such that $(1-x)/2 \geq 1/n$, and so $x + 1/n < 1$. Repeat the same procedure for the left endpoint if needed.

Comment: Why did you delete your full argument?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Was considering writing a different one because I think it holds for all open intervals in $R^1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct.
Another example is the real line with the standard metric topology $(\mathbb{R},d)$. The set $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed ( nor open) but every point is a limit point.